# Call function from Button Form App Visual Studio

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, amazon-s3

I'm trying to combine 2 codes: One is a Form App, where i get some information and the other is a Amazon Request for a bucket. I am having some trouble to call the function AWS() from the Program.cs to the Form1.cs, and get the information when i click on the form Button.

FORM1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string accessKey;

    private string GetAccessKey()
    {
        return accessKey;
    }

    private void SetAccessKey(string value)
    {
        accessKey = value;
    }

    private string privatekey;

    private string GetPrivatekey()
    {
        return privatekey;
    }

    private void SetPrivatekey(string value)
    {
        privatekey = value;
    }

    private string region;

    private string GetRegion()
    {
        return region;
    }

    private void SetRegion(string value)
    {
        region = value;
    }

    private string bucketname;

    private string GetBucketname()
    {
        return bucketname;
    }

    private void SetBucketname(string value)
    {
        bucketname = value;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox_AccessKey_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textbox_PrivateKey_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox_Region_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBoxBucketName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetAccessKey(textBox_AccessKey.Text);
        SetPrivatekey(textbox_PrivateKey.Text);
        SetRegion(textBox_Region.Text);
        SetBucketname(textBoxBucketName.Text);
        AWS(GetAccessKey(),GetPrivateKey(),GetBucketname());
    }
}
```

}

--------------------\---------------------\-----------

Program.CS

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
  class MakeS3RequestTest
  {
     static string accessKey = "******";
     static string secretKey = "********";
     private const string bucketName = "******";
     // Specify your bucket region (an example region is shown).
     private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.******;
     private static AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, bucketRegion);
     private static TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
     private static string directoryPath = "*******";


     public static async Task AWS(string accesskey, string privatekey, string bucketname)
     {

         using (client)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Listing objects stored in a bucket");
             ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
             ListObjectsResponse response = await client.ListObjectsAsync(request.BucketName = bucketName);
            // Process the response.
            foreach (S3Object obj in response.S3Objects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("key = {0}", obj.Key);
                try
                {
                    string filename = directoryPath + "\\" + obj.Key;
                    FileStream fs = File.Create(filename);
                    fs.Close();
                    fileTransferUtility.Download(filename, bucketName, obj.Key);

                }
                catch (Exception Excep)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Excep.Message, Excep.InnerException);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well you copy pasted the entire code from somewhere, so the Namespace of the AWS code is different from you Form. Either Fix that or Use "using Amazon.DocSamples.S3" in Form code.

Comment: You want to call AWS method which is in class `MakeS3RequestTest` from Button Click of Form1?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes.. after clicking on the button, i collect the necessary information and the AWS method should run.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I'm still learning C#, thats why part of the cod is copied. I tried what you said, but not worked

Comment: You can call method by doing `MakeS3RequestTest.AWS(GetAccessKey(),GetPrivateKey(),GetBucketname())`. Your code is not perfect and it needs lot more improvements. This solution will get you go for now. You need to read about classes, properties, methods etc in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you defined method `AWS` in class `MakeS3RequestTest`, and it is a static method.

So you can call it when clicking button via the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MakeS3RequestTest.AWS(/*params*/);
}
```